# What does a skill next to a conversation action mean?

Tags: the-sims-4

Some of the conversations and actions you can take with other persons have skill icons on them. For example cooking, charisma, etc. What does that mean? Will I practice my skill if I choose it? Is it there because I have the skill? Will it work better than others if my skill level is high? What's the deal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icons indicate that those interactions are unlocked at certain skill levels or with certain traits.  These interactions don't (generally) practice the skill.

While Sunglasses and Microphone interactions build Charisma and Comedy, other friendly and funny interactions do so as well.

The primary purpose of many of these interactions is to satisfy whims.

Comment: Hm, yeah, it seems it just varies... sometimes it seems skills light up in the skills list while using certain conversation topics, while other times it doesn't. Oh well \*shrug\*